# [indesign][js] dialog or palette - not show up

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

have problem with script.
need open a window with some information, which will automatically disappear after 3 seconds.
my code:

```
#targetengine "session"
var windowX = new Window("dialog"); // v2 palette
    windowX.orientation = "row"; 
    windowX.preferredSize.width = 200; 
    windowX.preferredSize.height = 200; 
    windowX.alignChildren = ["center","center"]; 
    windowX.spacing = 15; 
    windowX.margins = 16; 
    
var image1_imgString = "%C2%89PNG%0D%0A%1A..."
var image1 = windowX.add("image", undefined, File.decode(image1_imgString), {name: "image1"}); 
    windowX.show();
```

dialog show, palette not

if I add ...

```
var timerBreak = new Date().getTime() + 3000;
var now = new Date().getTime();
    while(now<timerBreak){
          now = new Date().getTime()
    }
    windowX.close();
```

nothing happend (happend: first: loop, next: window show and close at the same time) - why?
if i add ...

```
windowX.addEventListener('show',function(){
             ...
}
```

same ...
but if i add alert("dhgkjsd") ... for check ... dialog (or palette) show and wait for click on messagaebox

how to make a timer that will close the displayed window 3 seconds after opening?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I do not have a copy of InDesign to test this, but the code below works in AfterEffects.

```
#targetengine "session"

// To be called later
function closeMe() {
    windowX.close();
}

// Timer as a variable
var delay = 3000;

// a pallette, and not a modal, like in your
// original code, because the modal is UI blocking
var windowX = new Window("palette");

windowX.orientation = "row"; 
windowX.preferredSize.width = 200; 
windowX.preferredSize.height = 200; 
windowX.alignChildren = ["center","center"]; 
windowX.spacing = 15; 
windowX.margins = 16;
windowX.show();

// This is the key part
app.setTimeout(closeMe,delay);
```

`app.setTimeout()` [has been suggested](https://community.adobe.com/t5/after-effects-discussions/need-an-extendscript-timer/m-p/6117453) as a way of delaying code execution, which is what you need in this case (delaying of `windowX.close()`). Please note the author's comments (check the link) - `app.setTimeout()` has been made available from AE version CC 2015.

Comment: Alas, it doesn't work in InDesign. It seems InDesign has no `app.setTimeout()` method.

Comment: err no:24 : setTimeout is not a function

Answer (score 0):

It can be done this way:

```
var windowX = new Window("palette");
windowX.orientation = "row";
windowX.preferredSize.width = 200;
windowX.preferredSize.height = 200;
windowX.alignChildren = ["center","center"];
windowX.spacing = 15;
windowX.margins = 16;
// var image1_imgString = "%C2%89PNG%0D%0A%1A..."
// var image1 = windowX.add("image", undefined, File.decode(image1_imgString), {name: "image1"});
windowX.show();

// here is the magic
windowX.update();
$.sleep(3000); // 3 seconds
windowX.hide();
windowX = null;
```

Based on the example from here: https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator-discussions/auto-close-alert-message/td-p/9398258

Answer (score 0):

@Yuri ... windowX don't show before $.sleep (use instead var timerBreak...) - but only my Mac. Another Mac - your code works.

I write something like this:

```
//create windowX  
var oneIdleTask = app.idleTasks.add({
        name: "one_idle_task",
        sleep: 1
    }); // sleep not working here - write 3000 and nothing change

    var onIdleEventListener = oneIdleTask.addEventListener(IdleEvent.ON_IDLE,
        function() {
            var oneIdleTaskName = "one_idle_task";
            var oneIdleTask = app.idleTasks.itemByName(oneIdleTaskName);
            if (oneIdleTask != null) {
                oneIdleTask.remove();
                $.sleep(3000) //<- write sleep here ...  but deley is ok (for me) without this
                windowX.hide();
            }
        }
    );
    windowX.show();
```